# PhpExcel : Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper'

Tags: php, virtualbox, phpexcel

I have encountered this error

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper' not found in \VBOXSVR\ACACIASOFT\apc\spreadsheet\lib\phpexcel\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php on line 29

My currrent setup is :
Host Machine : Windows 7
             : this is where i check out my solution from svn

Virtual Box Guest Machine : 
             : Windows XP
             : where my apache, php, mysql installed.
             : I have also added the shared directory on my virtual box so that i will use this as the documentroot location

My dilemma started when i change the documentroot. it bring error on my phpexcel modules but when i changed back the documentroot c:/program files/apache.... copy the project to this directory. this will not bring any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable on php extension the zip dll

Comment: How to do that, please elaborate.

Answer (score 14):

The same problem has been nagging me to death for a whole day.
I found out that if you have your own autoloader function previously registered with spl, then you'll have to **return false** in the event your autoloader fails to load the required class, like this:

```
spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
function my_autoload($className)
{
    if(file_exists(CLASS_PREFIX.".$className.php"))
    {
        require_once(CLASS_PREFIX.".$className.php");
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @BhuvanRikka웃 Anywhere, in config file, before you start instantiating objects.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka웃 what should i give in the CLASS_PREFIX
its showing me undefined constant

Comment: @AmirthaRajan Just make sure that the path is perfect

Comment: @BhuvanRikka웃 Yeah works Perfect now, My server path was wrong, Thank You so much Bhuvan

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're running some other library with its own autoloader that interferes with the PHPExcel autoloader. The latest SVN code has been modified to prevent this problem.

In the /Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php script itself, change:

```
public static function Register() {
    return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
}   //  function Register()
```

to

```
public static function Register() {
    if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
        //    Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
        spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
    }
    //    Register ourselves with SPL
    return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'));
}    //    function Register()
```

Comment: Removing true, true from spl_autload_register solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone happens to be on Linux, then this error can be caused by incorrect usage rights.

I had this same issue, but I changed the owner of the 'Shared' folder, and set it to be 'www-data' user, which is the apache user on my system (chown www-data:www-data Shared). This fixed the "Class 'PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper' not found" error.

Yet this is not the full fix, What you really need to do is make sure the folders and files  in the PHPExcel folder are assigned to the correct user, and that they have the correct rights. Here is how you do it:

You need to assign the PHPExcel folder and every item in it to the www-data user so Apache can access the files. Make sure you are one level below your PHPExcel folder and then run this command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data PHPExcel
```

And that is that it. Apache should be able to access all the files and the error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know it's already a year ago, but since this problem occured to my setup (Virtual Machine running Windows 7 Professional in an Active Directory network with explicit user rights) just a few days ago i wanted to share my solution, maybe this will help others to save some time:

I figured out 2 problems (only on **WINDOWS** HOSTS!):

- the PHPEXCEL_ROOT-Constant is defined with wrong directory seperators

**MY SOLUTION:** change the php code to use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant in the defitinions
in the file: PHPExcel.php (around Line 32) like this:

```
//OLD: define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

there are 2 more files to change: "IOFactory.php" and "Settings.php" (Line 34) to:

```
//OLD: define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../');
define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

- the PHP function "is_readable" does not always return correct results on Windows hosts, in my case the file was readable but the result was *false*.

**MY WORKAROUND:** To work around this Bug, you can remove the "is_readable" check in the file "autoload.php" change line 77 to:

```
// if ((file_exists($pClassFilePath) === FALSE) || (is_readable($pClassFilePath) === FALSE)) {
if (file_exists($pClassFilePath) === FALSE) {
```